# How do I transfer voice memos from iTunes back to iPhone 5 voice memos

Tags: iphone, itunes

On my iPhone 5s, I have Voice Memos previously recorded. They were synced to iTunes on my Mac. The recordings still show on the iPhone as they normally would (date recorded and length/time) however, they no longer play on the iPhone and the cursor does not move on the sequencer bar after pushing the plat button. They do play in iTunes both on my Mac and on the iTunes program that is on my iPhone.

To resolve/transfer the Voice Memos back into Voice Memos on the iPhone I attempted the following: I opened iTunes on my Mac and found the recordings that I would like to transfer back to the Voice Memos program that is on my iPhone by dragging and dropping the selected recording under the Devices section into Voice Memos. The blue bar shows and appears the sync process occurred. The recording(s) still do not appear/play in the Voice Memos on the iPhone.

Any ideas how to accomplish this are most appreciated!